# line-height width fonts InkstonSans on Windows only

Tags: html, css, webfonts

CSS

```
.mgu-filter-to-select { 
    border: 1px solid #000000; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    float:left; 
    margin: 0; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    line-height: 1; 
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-family: InkstonSans; 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    padding: 5px;  
    }
```

On Mac, everthing is looking fine:
[image]

on Windows (exept mobile) it looks so
[image]

After some tests it seems, that the problem is the Font InkstonSans. Any idea how i can solve that?

thanks

Comment: .. to change the webfont it not possible;-)

Comment: use some conditional css that modifies it only the troubled platform (hacky) but that's css. ;)

Comment: which browser(s) on windows perform that way? you may have to do multiple conditionals to make optimal use of that web font.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately it ie, chrome, FF on Win 8 to 10..

Comment: using a more standard webfont may be a better solution check [here](https://fonts.google.com/) a real quick glance this one seemed close https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Economica (not sure if you can change font tho)

Comment: another font is dev. not the solution, design is allready sign-off.

Comment: conditional is only working for IE less v10, not v11!

Comment: @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) { // IE10+ CSS here } - See more at: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/write-conditional-css-ie10-and-11#sthash.zw3G7lXn.dpuf

Comment: thanks. but i need conditionals for IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, FF on Windows. Is there a conditional for windows system globaly?

Comment: not that i know of, you will have to stack all the required conditionals to achieve your result. a pain.... i know but non-standard fonts will cause huge issues. how are you loading that font for your "windows" users

Comment: you should spec a fallback if the user fails to have that font or it fails to load otherwise you get a times-new-roman or whatever their default is